# what is None in shape argument of tf.placeholder mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

```
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_features])
```

From the above, I under stand that the number of data is equal to `batch_size` and each data is `num_features` long

but

`X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])`
I really don't understand. Can you guys teach me? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `None` to a shape argument of a `tf.placeholder` tells it simply that that dimension is unspecified, and to infer that dimension from the tensor you are feeding it during run-time (when you run a session). Only some arguments (generally the `batch_size` argument) can be set to `None` since Tensorflow needs to be able to construct a working graph before run time. This is useful for when you don't want to specify a `batch_size` before run time.

Comment: Thank you so much!
One more question, is there any different between `shape=[batch_size, num_features]`
and `shape=(batch_size, num_features)`